# the actual value is not stored in variable when taking as double

Tags: c++, double, cin

When i input l=1 r=999999999999999999 k= 1000000000 the value of r gets changed to
1.0e+18.How can i take the actual variable input ?
This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
int main() {
    double l, r,k;
    cin >> l >> r >> k;
    double i = 1,c=0;
    while (i<=r)
    {
        if (i >= l) {
            cout <<fixed<<setprecision(0)<< i << " ";c++;
        }
        i *= k;
    }
    if (c == 0)cout << -1;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: That `#define` really hurts my eyes  ...

Comment: If you want to preserve the input, use a string instead of a numeric type.

Answer (score 6):

The value you're inputting for `r`, 999999999999999999, has 18 digits of precision. A `double` variable, however, can represent a bit less than 16 digits; thus, your value gets rounded up to 1.0e+18. Just for fun, try adding 1 to your value, and compare it to the original value - you'll find they're equal. Not just 'close' - equal. That's right - `r == r + 1`.

For a tutorial on some of the intricacies of floating point number I suggest you [take a look at this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html).

Best of luck.

Comment: So,the problem remains ,but thanks for the help and for the link also.

Comment: If you want this to work as you expect you might try changing the type of `r` to `long long`. However, the underlying issue of "how to handle large and small numbers without loss of precision" remains. To deal with that issue you need to consider a class library which can deal with numbers that exceed the precision or scale provided by the built-in hardware-associated types. One such class lib is the [TTMath library](http://www.ttmath.org/). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, you could store 999999999999999999 as a `long long` because that has a few more bits of precision. (It only supports integral numbers, so it doesn't need bits for an exponent).